# Java Regex that finds YYYY-MM even in a chaotic string

Tags: java, regex, expression

I need a regex to find the year and the month value from filenames that can get very chaotic. My example here is "SuSa_Q2Factory_2012-08.xls". My regexes get annoyed because of the single "2" in the companys name that people sometimes write into the filename, too.

Currently my regex is looking like this:

```
// Search for date of the Format 2012-02 / YYYY-MM
if (fileName.matches("[0-9]{4}[\\-\\_\\.\\,\\ ][0-9]{2}\\.(xls|xlsx)")) {
int year = Integer.parseInt(fileName.substring(0, 4));
int month = Integer.parseInt(fileName.substring(5, 7));
return new Month(year, month);
}

// Search for date of the Format 2012-2 / YYYY-M
if (fileName.matches("[0-9]{4}[\\-\\_\\.\\,\\ ][0-9]\\.(xls|xlsx)")) {
int year = Integer.parseInt(fileName.substring(0, 4));
int month = Integer.parseInt(fileName.substring(5, 6));
return new Month(year, month);
}
```

Comment: There is no need at all to ecape `-`, `_` or `.` or anything else than the dash and closing bracket in a character class! [-_., ]` is enough

Comment: Read a basic tutorial on regex.  (1) `{1,2}` would match 1 or 2 characters.  (2) `[]` denotes a character class.

Comment: [0-9]{4}(\.|\-|\_|\\)[0-9]{1,2} as devnull told already

Comment: did you people actually read the question? the problem wasn't about 1-2 numbers, it was about the company name. Having `{1,2}` in regex would fail the substring code, so that's not a viable suggestion either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Pattern` and the `Matcher` classes:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

[...]

String fileName = "SuSa_Q2Factory_2012-08.xls";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*([0-9]{4})[-_., ]([0-9]{1,2})\\.(xls|xlsx)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(fileName);
if (m.matches()) {
    int year = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
    int month = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
    System.out.printf("year = %d, month = %d\n", year, month);
}
```

This prints `year = 2012, month = 8`

Your code didn't work because a company name doesn't have a fixed length and hardcoded `substring` indexes won't do (You just don't know where `month-year` part of the string starts). You need to capture `month` and `year` in a regular expression group and extract them with the `Matcher.group(int)` method.

Comment: Thank you, this code works and is obviously a better approach in general. Today I learned about Pattern and Matcher :)